# ElasticSearch return only specific part of the document

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a JSON document mimicking the following structure.

```
{
"mydata": [
      {
        "Key1": "Hello",
        "Key2": "this",
        "Key3": "is",
        "Key4": "line one",
        "Key5": "of the file"
      },
      {
        "Key1": "Hello",
        "Key2": "this",
        "Key3": "is",
        "Key4": "line two",
        "Key5": "of the file"
      }]
}
```

The index I am using does not have any specific mappings as such. I am able to write a free-text Lucene query like

```
mydata.Key4:"line one"
```

which returns the entire document as a result. However, in my case, I would only like to retrieve the first part of the JSON object as the result. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
{
        "Key1": "Hello",
        "Key2": "this",
        "Key3": "is",
        "Key4": "line one",
        "Key5": "of the file"
}
```

I found that I can retrieve specific fields using `_source_includes` and passing the required keys, however, I am not able to find an equivalent to return all the keys within a specific part of the JSON document that matches the query. Is it because of how the file is being indexed? Could anyone guide me here?

**EDIT:**

I dropped my index and updated the mapping as follows

```
{
"mappings" : {
     
  "properties" : {
   "data" : {
    "type" : "nested"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I re-indexed the document, quickly skimmed through ES documentation and ran the following nested query.

```
{
"_source": false,
  "query": {
       "nested": {
          "path": "data",
          "query": {
          "match": { 
               "data.Key4": "line one" 
          }
       },
       "inner_hits": {} 
  }
 }
}
```

However, this also returns all the documents in my index, except that now the returned results are under `inner_hits`

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.52889514,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "QAZJ-nMBi6fwNevjDQJy",
            "_score": 0.52889514,
            "inner_hits": {
                "data": {
                    "hits": {
                        "total": {
                            "value": 2,
                            "relation": "eq"
                        },
                        "max_score": 0.87546873,
                        "hits": [{
                            "_index": "myindex",
                            "_type": "_doc",
                            "_id": "QAZJ-nMBi6fwNevjDQJy",
                            "_nested": {
                                "field": "data",
                                "offset": 0
                            },
                            "_score": 0.87546873,
                            "_source": {
                                "Key1": "Hello",
                                "Key2": "this",
                                "Key3": "is",
                                "Key4": "line one",
                                "Key5": "of the file"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "_index": "myindex",
                            "_type": "_doc",
                            "_id": "QAZJ-nMBi6fwNevjDQJy",
                            "_nested": {
                                "field": "data",
                                "offset": 1
                            },
                            "_score": 0.18232156,
                            "_source": {
                                "Key1": "Hello",
                                "Key2": "this",
                                "Key3": "is",
                                "Key4": "line two",
                                "Key5": "of the file"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not defining `mapping`, that's the main problem. When you keep your data the way you mentioned, it will be kept as individual properties of type `text`.

When you perform search, it will bring the entire document. But if you define `nested` mapping for `mydata` then you can make use of `inner_hits` to retrieve only matching documents.

**Edit:**

**Query to be used:**

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "inner_hits": {        
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": { //To look for exact match
                "data.Key4.keyword": "line one" //need to match line one not line two
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What happens when you use match:**

`line one` will be tokenised as below

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "line",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "one",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Similarly it creates two tokens `line`, `two`.

So when you use `match`, it is full text search queries. It does analyse on index time and search time. So during search time, `line one` will be analysed and ES looks for either `line` or `one`. `line two` contains token `line` hence that is also part of the result.

To avoid that, you have to avoid analysing. So `term queries` has to be used. It looks for exact match.

Comment: I understand. However, I see that in all the example cases given for nested queries, the key is always specified when the query is run. Like mydata.Key4:"line one". If I change the data type to nested, could I still run a free text query like "line one" and return only that document?

Comment: Yes. You need to reindex the data as mapping needs to be modified

Comment: And as I mentioned you need to use nested query with inner hits.

Comment: I did try with updated mapping and used inner hits to retrieve the matching documents, still no luck. Could you help me out here?

Comment: @FAlonso The result you get now is correct, you only get the nested inner hit that matches your query. The thing is that matching `line one` with match `line one` and `line two` as well, because the token `line` matches both nested documents. What you probably want is an exact match, so either use the `term` query (instead of `match`) or match on the `data.Key4.keyword` field.

Comment: Ah, got it! I did try using term query, but no results were returned. Using ````keyword```` did the trick. Thanks!